# AWS Tutorial - Pushing Docker Image to AWS ECR error x509

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, x509, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I'm working towards through the AWS [Build a Modern Web Application project](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-two/) and have come across a problem at Module 2B part 1C (Confusing but will make sense if you go to the link).

Command used:

```
$ docker push muhammad.h.mughal.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest
```

I can't seem to push the docker image I have created. The error reads:

```
    The push refers to repository [muhammad.h.mughal.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service]
Get https://muhammad.h.mughal.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, not muhammad.h.mughal.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I thought it would be a simple task however I have been stuck on this for a while now and am reaching out. If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because the name you're using for the repository, `muhammad.h.mughal`, has `.` periods in it.

You'll note the host you're referring to is `muhammad.h.mughal.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` but the certificate is for `*.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.  `*` in this context ( ssl certificate Common Names) matches only one domain component.  By adding a `.` in your naming, you've inadvertently created a domain name with *3* domain components (`muhammad`,`h`,and `mughal`), invalidating ssl certificate of ECR.

The solution, though drastic, is simple - delete the repo.  That name will never work correctly, and now is the time to start over.